# Is there an algebraic way to determine the integration limits for a multiple integral without drawing the domain of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

For a single-variable integral, when we do substitution, we just simply evaluate the substitution function by plugging in each endpoint of the original integral limits. But for a double integral, or multi-variable integral, usually we need to draw the integration region first. Especially when compute triple integral, drawing the integration region is time consuming. For higher dimensional integral, ($n$ variables in general), it is almost impossible to draw the region or visualize the integral limit intuitively.

So my question is: is there a systematic way to find the integration limit for multi-variable integral that is as simple as in the single-variable case? Especially, when the coordinate is non-cartesian, or the integration region is defined piecewise or blockwise in the 3d case. One usually has to draw the region and visualize it geometrically to determine the integral limit. Is it possible to do everything algebriacally without drawing the geometry?

Comment: If you are evaluating $\int_{x=0}^{x=10} \int_{y=0}^{y=x} \int_{z=0}^{z=y}$, this is integrating on the region $\{(x,y,z)\,:\, 0 \leq x \leq 10,\ 0 \leq y \leq x,\ 0 \leq z \leq y\}$, which can be written as just $0\leq z \leq y \leq x \leq 10$. From this, you can pick whichever variable you want first, and see how big or small it could possibly be. Like $y$ could be anywhere in $[0, 10]$, but with $y$ fixed, then $x$ could be anywhere in $[y, 10]$ and $z$ could be anywhere in $[0, y]$. So you could write $\int_{y=0}^{y=10} \int_{x=y}^{x=10} \int_{z=0}^{z=y}$, all without geometry.

Comment: Yes, this is a good example. But what if more complicated case, such as non-cartecian coordinate, or the integration region is piecewised, or block-wised in 3d case. It has to draw the region and visualize it geometrically to determine the integral limit. Is it possible to do everything algebriacally without drawing the geometry?

Comment: Theoretically, yes, it is always *possible* to go without geometric intuition -- when changing variables, you're ultimately computing the image of your region under some transformation, reasoning about which tuples of numbers you can possibly get out. Like "I have these (x,y,z) tuples. Now which $(r, \theta, \phi)$ tuples does this correspond to?" But I don't think you're going to find much of a general procedure: computing images under functions can be hard, especially if you want to use a super-weird coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you ,do you mind to put your comment into an answer?